# Merging two Lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two tables. One is given by

```
T1 = Table[{x, y, 0.}, {x, 0, V},{y, 0, V}]
```

and from a calculation I have the second, a list of points {x, y, z}

```
T2 = {{0, 0, 3.4}, {1, 2, 1.4}, {10, 2, 7.4}, ...}
```

with `Length[T1] > Length[T2]`.

How can I efficiently replace every element `{x, y, 0.}` in T1 by the corresponding point `{x, y, z}` from `T2`?

Comment: But which `{x,y,z}` will replace the `{x,y,0.}`? With `T1` being longer than `T2` if there are more `{x,y,0}` in `T1` than there are `{x,y,z}` in `T2`, what happens then?

Comment: @PlatoManiac: there is always only one point with the coordinates {x,y}. It has the value z. This value z has to replace the 0. in the "template" table T1. The reason why I'm trying to do it like this is the speed of Interpolation[]: When the values of T1 are integrated into a "rectangular" Table form as T1 the interpolation is much faster then for T2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 t1 = Table[{x, y, 0.}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]
 (* {{{0, 0, 0.}, {0, 1, 0.}, {0, 2, 0.}, {0, 3, 0.}, {0, 4, 0.}, {0, 5, 0.}},
     {{1, 0, 0.}, {1, 1, 0.}, {1, 2, 0.}, {1, 3, 0.}, {1, 4,  0.}, {1, 5, 0.}}, 
     {{2, 0, 0.}, {2, 1, 0.}, {2, 2, 0.}, {2, 3,  0.}, {2, 4, 0.}, {2, 5, 0.}}, 
     {{3, 0, 0.}, {3, 1, 0.}, {3, 2, 0.}, {3, 3, 0.}, {3, 4, 0.}, {3, 5, 0.}}, 
     {{4, 0, 0.}, {4, 1, 0.}, {4, 2, 0.}, {4, 3, 0.}, {4, 4, 0.}, {4, 5, 0.}}, 
     {{5, 0, 0.}, {5, 1, 0.}, {5, 2, 0.}, {5, 3, 0.}, {5, 4, 0.}, {5, 5, 0.}}} *)
```

Use the second table, say,

```
 t2 = DeleteDuplicates[RandomInteger[5, {5, 3}], #1[[;; 2]] == #2[[;; 2]] &]
 (* {{0, 5, 3}, {4, 3, 3}, {1, 4, 4}, {5, 3, 0}, {2, 5, 3}} *)
```

to define the replacement rules:

```
 rplcmntRule = {#[[1]], #[[2]], _} -> # & /@ t2
 (*  {{0, 5, _} -> {0, 5, 3}, {4, 3, _} -> {4, 3, 3}, 
      {1, 4, _} -> {1, 4, 4}, {5, 3, _} -> {5, 3, 0}, {2, 5, _} -> {2, 5, 3}}*)
```

and use them in `ReplaceAll`:

```
 t1 /. rplcmntRule
 (* {{{0, 0, 0.}, {0, 1, 0.}, {0, 2, 0.}, {0, 3, 0.}, {0, 4, 0.}, {0, 5, 3}}, 
     {{1, 0, 0.}, {1, 1, 0.}, {1, 2, 0.}, {1, 3, 0.}, {1, 4, 4}, {1, 5, 0.}},
     {{2, 0, 0.}, {2, 1, 0.}, {2, 2, 0.}, {2, 3, 0.}, {2, 4, 0.}, {2, 5, 3}},
     {{3, 0, 0.}, {3, 1, 0.}, {3, 2, 0.}, {3, 3, 0.}, {3, 4, 0.}, {3, 5, 0.}}, 
     {{4, 0, 0.}, {4, 1, 0.}, {4, 2, 0.}, {4, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 0.}, {4, 5, 0.}},
     {{5, 0, 0.}, {5, 1, 0.}, {5, 2, 0.}, {5, 3, 0}, {5, 4, 0.}, {5, 5, 0.}}} *)
```

Comment: You beat me again. :-)

Comment: Mathematica can be SO elegant, thank you kguler!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you should should have selected `v=2`:)

Comment: @pawel, thank you for the accept. Please keep in mind that it is a good idea to wait for a while before accepting an answer as questions with accepted answers tend to attract less attention from potential answerers.

Answer (score 9):

First, you should not start user Symbol names with capital letters as these can easily conflict with internal system functions.

There are surely quite a few ways of doing this.  It is not clear if you value performance over clarity, etc.

#### Replace by pattern

Ignoring the regularity of the data (and applicable to cases where it is not) you could use replacement rules:

```
v = 3;
t1 = Table[{x, y, 0.}, {x, 0, v}, {y, 0, v}];
t2 = {{0, 0, 3.4}, {1, 2, 1.4}, {3, 2, 7.4}};

rules = {#, #2, _} -> {##} & @@@ t2

t1 /. rules
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, _} -> {0, 0, 3.4}, {1, 2, _} -> {1, 2, 1.4}, {3, 2, _} -> {3, 2, 7.4}}
>
> {{{0, 0, 3.4}, {0, 1, 0.}, {0, 2, 0.}, {0, 3, 0.}},
>  {{1, 0, 0.}, {1, 1, 0.}, {1, 2, 1.4}, {1, 3, 0.}},
>  {{2, 0, 0.}, {2, 1, 0.}, {2, 2, 0.}, {2, 3, 0.}},
>  {{3, 0, 0.}, {3, 1, 0.}, {3, 2, 7.4}, {3, 3, 0.}}}
> ```

Be aware that these patterns will match only if the first two elements exactly match; for an equivalence use:

```
rules = {x_ /; x == #, y_ /; y == #2, _} :> {x, y, #3} & @@@ t2
```

#### Replace by index

Using the regularity of the data we could make these replacements directly, using `ReplacePart` or for in-place modification assignments to `Part`.  We must adjust for the fact that your indices start from zero whereas *Mathematica* indexes from one.

```
ReplacePart[t1, {# + 1, #2 + 1, 3} :> #3 & @@@ t2]
```

> ```
> {{{0, 0, 3.4}, {0, 1, 0.}, {0, 2, 0.}, {0, 3, 0.}},
>  {{1, 0, 0.}, {1, 1, 0.}, {1, 2, 1.4}, {1, 3, 0.}},
>  {{2, 0, 0.}, {2, 1, 0.}, {2, 2, 0.}, {2, 3, 0.}},
>  {{3, 0, 0.}, {3, 1, 0.}, {3, 2, 7.4}, {3, 3, 0.}}}
> ```